# JPA multiple persistence persistence units and JTA transaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, osgi

I have an OSGi project with multiple bundles containing JPA model classes as well as the corresponding persistence.xml. All PUs use JTA as its transaction-type and are connected to the same database (they use the same DataSource).

When manipulating entities I use different EntityManagers and everything is working fine as long as I use an XADataSource. My thinking now is that since they use the same database and the same transaction-manager XA transactions shouldn't be necessary. Though if I switch to a plain DataSource I start seeing inconsistencies in case of rollbacks.

I looked through the specs but couldn't find anything related to this. Does anyone have a pointer whether XA transactions are required as part of such a setup?

Thanks,
Philipp

Answer (score 2):

If you use different persistence units then each will have its own connection to the database. So even if you use the same DataSource they will not use the same transaction. So I think this is why you might have problems during rollback.

In jta the transaction can span the different connections and so it works.

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable. Would be nice to see this somewhere in the official specs documented. Its always hard to get this things working in OSGi so you never know if it is due to the setup or if it is supposed to work this way :)

Comment: The topic of jpa and jta in OSGi is really quite complicated (only partly because of OSGi). Not sure how to improve this as there are so many things to consider.